# Undefined answer in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
switch(e){
  case "A+": f="EXCELLENT";    break;
  case "A-": f="VERY GOOD";    break;
  case "B+": f="G00D";         break;
  case "B" : f="SATISFACTORY"; break;
  default:   f="FAIL";
}

document.write("<b>AVERAGE=</b>",ave)
document.write("<br>LETTER GRADE=",e)
```

Why does the letter grade answered "undefined"? What way can I solve it?

Comment: Hi. In the future, please try to format your code correctly before posting a question. Have a look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). You also need to post enough code for us to reproduce your issue. Here, we can only see that you are using 2 variables (`ave` and `e`) that are defined nowhere in the code you posted. You won't get an answer if you don't add more code.

Comment: This code is incomplete. Please show the whole relevant code so we can help you.

Comment: apparently f is fail also, you need to show the code that is involving e, maybe then we can help you.

Comment: [This is off topic (#1)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you get an undefined answer.
Try this code with [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), This worked for me:

```
var e = 'A+';
var ave = 'B+';
switch(e){
  case "A+": f="EXCELLENT";    break;
  case "A-": f="VERY GOOD";    break;
  case "B+": f="G00D";         break;
  case "B" : f="SATISFACTORY"; break;
  default:   f="FAIL";
}

document.write("<b>AVERAGE=</b>",ave)
document.write("<br>LETTER GRADE=",f)
```